# "dyld: Library not loaded" while running openCV on Eclipse CDT (Mountain Lion)

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, libraries, dyld

---

**DEAR PEOPLE OF THE FUTURE:** This turned out to be an issue with the build path in Eclipse. Couldn't find a way to edit the build path manually so I ended up using XCode with all the same Library and Compiler settings. Worked like a charm.

---

I am using Eclipse CDT 64 bit with binary parser Mach-O 64 bit.

I ran a brew install of opencv 2.4.6.1.

In Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > MacOS X C++ Linker > Libraries:

- Libraries (-l): opencv_highgui and opencv_core.
- Library Search Path (-L): /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.6.1/lib

In Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > MacOS X C++ Compiler > Includes:

- Include Paths (-l): /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.6.1/include/opencv/
- Include Files (-include): empty

The build runs fine, no errors or warnings.

When I Run the project as a Local C/C++ Application, I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.6.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/dashielms/Documents/workspace/test/Debug/test
Reason: image not found
```

I don't know why it is looking in /usr/local/opt/opencv/, I checked in Terminal and the directory doesn't exist. I created a shortcut there named opencv that linked to /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.6.1/, but then it told me that:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/dashielms/Documents/workspace/test/Debug/test
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.6.dylib: stat() failed with errno=20
```

The code is as follows:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
  cvNamedWindow( "My Window", 1 );
  IplImage *img = cvCreateImage( cvSize( 640, 480 ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
  CvFont font;
  double hScale = 1.0;
  double vScale = 1.0;
  int lineWidth = 1;
  cvInitFont( &font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX | CV_FONT_ITALIC,
              hScale, vScale, 0, lineWidth );
  cvPutText( img, "Hello World!", cvPoint( 200, 400 ), &font,
             cvScalar( 255, 255, 0 ) );
  cvShowImage( "My Window", img );
  cvWaitKey();
  return 0;
}
```

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cscud.png

I also noticed that in my Includes drop-down there are a ton of folders and most of them aren't used. Should they all be there? And if not, how do I remove them?

Thank you!